# Given a morphism how to determine that the question is local on target or source?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the theory of schemes of algebriac geometry,given a morphism of schemes $f:X \to Y$,the technique of reducing the question to a simple situation could simlify the proof. For instance, the property of closed immersion is local on $Y$, thus we may assume that $Y$ is affine. So for the morphism of schemes,such as finte,of finite type,separated,proper,closed immersion and so on, how to determine that the question is local or not? Furthermore,local on the target $Y$ or source $X$ ? I don't konw how to judge these,but this technique,that is reducing the question to a simple situation, is very useful in the algebraic geometry especially. Any help will be greatly appreciated,and thanks in advanced !

Comment: When you say "I do't know how to judge these", what kind of answer do you expect? I  would suggest read a few of these proofs and see how they are decided-usually by attempting to see whether it is local (on $Y$ or $X$), not  by guessing.

Comment: @Mohan It's true that I don't know why they can do such assumption, for me , I can't simplify the question to a easy situation.So many exercises are hard to do. I want to learn the technique of reducing. Do an special assumption,it's easy to deal and the question is local,so we're done,it's cool.That's why I ask such question . I want to get some advice or guidance. thank you for your comment

Comment: May be check some specific ones and see how it works. For example, check that a morphism is affine is local on $Y$ but not local on $X$, a morphism is proper is local on $Y$, but not local on $X$.

Comment: @Mohan I'll verify these morphisms one by one,thank you for your kind help